# How the circle size should get increase or decrease dynamically based on the input using javascript/css

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Need to create 2 circles based on the input the circle size should get increase or decrease dynamically using javascript/css

Can any one help me out on this.?!

TIA

Comment: Please share what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something to get you started. It uses a [custom property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) and adjusts as you type. I through in a `CSS` transition to make it look cooler when growing/shrinking.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('.circle-size');
const circles = document.querySelectorAll('.circle');

input.addEventListener('input', handleInput);

function handleInput() {
  circles.forEach(circle => {
    circle.style.setProperty('--circle-size', input.value + 'px');
  })
}
```

```css
.circle {
  margin-right: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: var(--circle-size, 20px);
  height: var(--circle-size, 20px);  
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.5s width, 0.5s height;
}

[type=number] {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>

<input aria-label="set circle size" type="number" class="circle-size" value="20">
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8xmfzr64/2/)

Comment: Thanks Andy Hoffman, Let me try with this. Actually am getting the % as input i need to calculate based on that the circle size should get adjusted.

Comment: @Purushoth I think you can take things from here. If this helped you, though, please mark my answer as the selected answer.

Comment: Hi Andy Hoffman

I tried with the below sample code

html:
<div class="centerCircle" [ngStyle]="setCircleStyle(79)"></div>

script:

  setCircleStyle(value) {
    let myStyles;
    const cssValue = value + 'px';
    myStyles = {
      '--circle-size': cssValue
    };
    return myStyles;
  }

css:

.centerCircle{
  margin-right: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: var(--circle-size, 40px);
  height: var(--circle-size, 40px);
  position: relative;
  background-color:#01bab9;
}

with the above code the styles not getting append.

Comment: @Purushoth It's pretty hard to help you by reading through code in a comment. I would recommend creating a new question with the complete code showing everything you've tried. That will give your question the best chance to get a good, complete answer.

Comment: Hi Andy, 
Here am  sharing the link from fiddle .  
https://jsfiddle.net/c2gr0dLb/1/

Comment: @Purushoth Are you trying to run Angular code? Your example is not using the Angular framework. You have an error in the console.

Comment: yes am running it via angular, i don't have any errors in my local code. might be some copy paste error i guess.

Comment: Maybe try to recreate your example in [CodeSandbox](http://codesandbox.io/)

Comment: yes am running it via angular, i don't have any errors in my local code. might be some copy paste error i guess.

Here am sharing stackbliz url : 

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vknnp2

Comment: @Purushoth I have it working [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1g28xl?file=src/app/app.component.ts) but it probably isn't the Angular way to do it. You may want to ask an Angular question about how to refactor it?

Comment: This is more than enough. Thanks a lot for taking your time to help me out.